# Can I do type introspection with trait objects and then downcast it?

Tags: rust

I have a collection of `Trait`, a function that iterates over it and does something, and then I would like to check the implementor type and if it is of type `Foo` then downcast it and call some Foo method.

Basically, something similar to Go's [type-switch](https://golang.org/doc/effective_go.html#type_switch) and [interface conversion](https://golang.org/doc/effective_go.html#interface_conversions).

Searching around I found about the [Any trait](http://doc.rust-lang.org/core/any/index.html) but it can only be implemented on `'static` types.

To help demonstrate what I want:

```
let vec: Vec<Box<Trait>> = //

for e in vec.iter() {
    e.trait_method();

    // if typeof e == Foo {
    // let f = e as Foo;
    // f.foo_method();
    //}
}
```

Comment: Are you sure that you need downcasting (it should be avoided as much as possible)? If you control either `Trait` or `Foo`, you could most probably avoid it.

Comment: This seems like the scenario that `Enum`s where made for.

Comment: @goertzenator would you please provide an example? I am facing almost the same problem and do not understand how to use enums properly to solve this problem. Thanks in advance

Answer (score 9, accepted):

As you have noticed, downcasting only works with `Any` trait, and yes, it only supports `'static` data. You can find a recent discussion on why it is so [here](http://www.reddit.com/r/rust/comments/2r25rf/why_does_any_only_work_for_t_static/). Basically, implementing reflection for references of arbitrary lifetimes is difficult.

It is also impossible (as of now, at least) to combine `Any` with your custom trait easily. However, a [macro library](https://github.com/chris-morgan/mopa) for automatic implementation of `Any` for your trait has recently been created. You can also find some discussion on it [here](http://www.reddit.com/r/rust/comments/2ricdw/mopa_my_own_personal_any_a_macro_to_implement_all/).

Answer (score 3):

This isn't a Rust-specific problem, although the vocabulary may be a little different. The ideal way to solve a problem like this, not just with traits in Rust but in any language, is to add the desired behavior (`foo_method` in your example) to the abstract interface (`Trait`):

```rust
trait Trait {
    fn trait_method(&self);
    fn foo_method(&self) {} // does nothing by default
}

struct Foo;

impl Trait for Foo {
    fn trait_method(&self) {
        println!("In trait_method of Foo");
    }

    fn foo_method(&self) {
        // override default behavior
        println!("In foo_method");
    }
}

struct Bar;

impl Trait for Bar {
    fn trait_method(&self) {
        println!("In trait_method of Bar");
    }
}

fn main() {
    let vec: Vec<Box<dyn Trait>> = vec![Box::new(Foo), Box::new(Bar)];

    for e in &vec {
        e.trait_method();
        e.foo_method();
    }
}
```

In this example, I have put a default implementation of `foo_method` in `Trait` which does nothing, so that you don't have to define it in every `impl` but only the one(s) where it applies. You should *really* attempt to make the above work before you resort to downcasting to a concrete type, which has serious drawbacks that all but erase the advantages of having trait objects in the first place.

That said, there are cases where downcasting may be necessary, and Rust does support it -- although the interface is a little clunky. You can downcast `&Trait` to `&Foo` by adding an intermediate *up*cast to `&Any`:

```rust
use std::any::Any;

trait Trait {
    fn as_any(&self) -> &dyn Any;
}

struct Foo;

impl Trait for Foo {
    fn as_any(&self) -> &dyn Any {
        self
    }
}

fn downcast<T: Trait + 'static>(this: &dyn Trait) -> Option<&T> {
    this.as_any().downcast_ref()
}
```

`as_any` has to be a method in `Trait` because it needs access to the concrete type. Now you can attempt to call `Foo` methods on a `Trait` trait object like this ([complete playground example](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2018&gist=2064fe79c47b442e3edce8f131629b00)):

```rust
if let Some(r) = downcast::<Foo>(&**e) {
    r.foo_method();
}
```

To make this work, you have to specify what type you expect (`::<Foo>`) and use `if let` to handle what happens when the referenced object is not an instance of `Foo`. You can't downcast a trait object to a concrete type unless you know exactly *what* concrete type it is.

If you ever need to know the concrete type, trait objects are almost useless anyway! You probably should use an `enum` instead, so that you will get compile-time errors if you omit to handle a variant somewhere. Furthermore, you can't use `Any` with non-`'static` structs, so if any `Foo` might need to contain a reference, this design is a dead end. The best solution, if you can do it, is to add `foo_method` to the trait itself.