# Rc<Trait> to Option<T>?

Tags: rust, trait-objects

I'm trying to implement a method that looks like:

```
fn concretify<T: Any>(rc: Rc<Any>) -> Option<T> {
    Rc::try_unwrap(rc).ok().and_then(|trait_object| {
        let b: Box<Any> = unimplemented!();
        b.downcast().ok().map(|b| *b)
    })
}
```

However, `try_unwrap` doesn't work on trait objects (which makes sense, as they're unsized). My next thought was to try to find some function that unwraps `Rc<Any>` into `Box<Any>` directly. The closest thing I could find would be

```
if Rc::strong_count(&rc) == 1 {
    Some(unsafe {
        Box::from_raw(Rc::into_raw(rc))
    })
} else {
    None
}
```

However, `Rc::into_raw()` appears to require that the type contained in the `Rc` to be `Sized`, and I'd ideally not like to have to use `unsafe` blocks.

Is there any way to implement this?

[Playground Link](https://play.rust-lang.org/?gist=a1e05e1d299c5ecffc9c57600a3f6c5e&version=stable&backtrace=2), I'm looking for an implementation of `rc_to_box` here.

Comment: There is a dissonance here: `Option<T>` *own* the `T`, whilst `Rc<Any>` is only one of the *co-owners* of the object. I can see two ways of handling this: returning `None` if there are multiple owners or converting the function to convert from `&Rc<Any>` to `Option<&T>`. Is the first one really what you want?

Comment: That's what the [`try_unwrap`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/rc/struct.Rc.html#method.try_unwrap) is for -- it ensures that the given `Rc` is the only owner. "`concretify`" should return `None` if either there are multiple owners or if the `Any` is not `T`.

Comment: Just checking :) In this case, are you okay with `None` or would you rather return a `Result` which specify in its `Err` field whether the issue is a mismatched type or multiple owners?

Comment: If I were a better person, I'd want the `Result` :) If it's only possible with a `Result`, I'll certainly accept that, but I'm relatively certain that the semantics of the problem are the same, regardless of whether I use `Option`, `Result`, or `panic!("something bad happened guys")`

Comment: Yes, it's only a cosmetic change :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Unfortunately, it appears that the API of `Rc` is lacking the necessary method to be able to get ownership of the wrapped type when it is `!Sized`.

The only method which may return the interior item of a `Rc` is `Rc::try_unwrap`, however it returns `Result<T, Rc<T>>` which requires that `T` be `Sized`.

In order to do what you wish, you would need to have a method with a signature: `Rc<T> -> Result<Box<T>, Rc<T>>`, which would allow `T` to be `!Sized`, and from there you could extract `Box<Any>` and perform the `downcast` call.

However, this method is impossible due to how `Rc` is implemented. Here is a stripped down version of `Rc`:

```
struct RcBox<T: ?Sized> {
    strong: Cell<usize>,
    weak: Cell<usize>,
    value: T,
}

pub struct Rc<T: ?Sized> {
    ptr: *mut RcBox<T>,
    _marker: PhantomData<T>,
}
```

Therefore, the only `Box` you can get out of `Rc<T>` is `Box<RcBox<T>>`.

Note that the design is severely constrained here:

- single-allocation mandates that all 3 elements be in a single `struct`
- `T: ?Sized` mandates that `T` be the last field

so there is little room for improvement in general.

---

However, in your specific case, it is definitely possible to improve on the generic situation. It does, of course, require `unsafe` code. And while it works fairly well with `Rc`, implementing it with `Arc` would be complicated by the potential data-races.

Oh... and the code is provided as is, no warranty implied ;)

```
use std::any::Any;
use std::{cell, mem, ptr};
use std::rc::Rc;

struct RcBox<T: ?Sized> {
    strong: cell::Cell<usize>,
    _weak: cell::Cell<usize>,
    value: T,
}

fn concretify<T: Any>(rc: Rc<Any>) -> Option<T> {
    //  Will be responsible for freeing the memory if there is no other weak
    //  pointer by the end of this function.
    let _guard = Rc::downgrade(&rc);

    unsafe {
        let killer: &RcBox<Any> = {
            let killer: *const RcBox<Any> = mem::transmute(rc);
            &*killer 
        };

        if killer.strong.get() != 1 { return None; }

        //  Do not forget to decrement the count if we do take ownership,
        //  as otherwise memory will not get released.
        let result = killer.value.downcast_ref().map(|r| {
            killer.strong.set(0);
            ptr::read(r as *const T)
        });

        //  Do not forget to destroy the content of the box if we did not
        //  take ownership
        if result.is_none() {
            let _: Rc<Any> = mem::transmute(killer as *const RcBox<Any>);
        }

        result
    }
}

fn main() {
    let x: Rc<Any> = Rc::new(1);
    println!("{:?}", concretify::<i32>(x));
}
```

Answer (score 2):

I don't think it's possible to implement your `concretify` function if you're expecting it to move the original value back out of the `Rc`; see [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40024093/downcast-traits-inside-rc-for-ast-manipulation) for why.

If you're willing to return a clone, it's straightforward:

```
fn concretify<T: Any+Clone>(rc: Rc<Any>) -> Option<T> {
    rc.downcast_ref().map(Clone::clone)
}
```

Here's a test:

```
#[derive(Debug,Clone)]
struct Foo(u32);

#[derive(Debug,Clone)]
struct Bar(i32);

fn main() {
    let rc_foo: Rc<Any> = Rc::new(Foo(42));
    let rc_bar: Rc<Any> = Rc::new(Bar(7));
    
    let foo: Option<Foo> = concretify(rc_foo);
    println!("Got back: {:?}", foo);
    let bar: Option<Foo> = concretify(rc_bar);
    println!("Got back: {:?}", bar);
}
```

This outputs:

> Got back: Some(Foo(42))
>
> Got back: None

[Playground](https://play.rust-lang.org/?gist=245b4e6077c136b4df75b58a909bb00b&version=stable&backtrace=0)

If you want something more "movey", and creating your values is cheap, you could also make a dummy, use `downcast_mut()` instead of `downcast_ref()`, and then `std::mem::swap` with the dummy.

Comment: I'm afraid I'm not sure what part of the linked question prevents going from `Box<Any>` to `T`; that's what [`Box<Any>::downcast()`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/boxed/struct.Box.html#method.downcast) does. I'm just trying (at this point) to convert `Rc<Trait>` to `Box<Trait>`. (Editing question to clarify this)

Comment: Hmm, I always forget that part of the `Any` docs are under `Box<Any>`!  Good point, it isn't clear and now I'm less sure; I'll see if I can improve my answer later.