# How to safely cast a Rc<Box<A>> into Rc<Box<B>> if trait B : A

Tags: casting, rust, traits

I have a situation similar to the following:

```
use std::rc::Rc;
trait A {}
trait B: A {}
struct Impl {}

impl A for Impl {}
impl B for Impl {}
```

I would like to be able to cast trait objects of these traits like in the following:

```
fn main() {
    let val: Rc<Box<A>> = Rc::new(Box::new(Impl {}));
    let test: Rc<Box<B>> = val as Rc<Box<B>>;
}
```

This gives me a compiler-error that this is a non-scalar cast. I guess I am doing the wrong sort of cast, but I do not see how this is supported. Further, I would like the cast to be safe, i.e. returning me an `Option<Rc<Box<B>>`. Is this possible or is the dynamic dispatch implemented such that trait objects cannot be converted between traits?

*Edit:* I forgot to say, I am using the nightly version, in case this should matter.

Comment: @Shepmaster Thanks for pointing out my mistake to forget the braces when creating a new object. I do not get the error regarding the trait bound that `A` should be `Sized`, though.

Comment: Perhaps a duplicate of [Why doesn't Rust support trait object upcasting?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/28632968/155423), or [Downcast traits inside Rc for AST manipulation](http://stackoverflow.com/q/40024093/155423). Note that the term you are probably searching for is "downcast" or "upcast", depending on direction.

Comment: FWIW, `struct Impl;` allows for `let a = Impl`. The lack of braces on the definition has meaning.