# Sharing weak trait object references

Tags: rust, traits, trait-objects

I'm trying to provide "views" of non-owned structs to separate components of a system.

Assume a set of traits with distinct methods: `Drawable`, `Modifiable` and a number of structs which implement at least one of the traits - `SimpleBox`, `Panel`, `Expression`.

Different components of the system will need to frequently access sequences of these objects, using methods of specific traits; consider a `DrawingManager` or a `ModifyManager`:

```
struct DrawingManager {
    items: Vec<Weak<Drawable>>,
}

struct ModifyManager {
    items: Vec<Weak<Modifiable>>
}
```

While a single object may be referenced in both managers, assume that there is a separate single owner of all structs:

```
struct ObjectManager {
    boxes: Vec<Rc<Box>>,
    panels: Vec<Rc<Panel>>,
    expressions: Vec<Rc<Expression>>,
}
```

Ideally, it would be useful to be able to manage deleting structs from one place - i.e simply removing it from the `ObjectManager` being enough to invalidate references in all other components (hence the use of `Weak`).

- Is there a way of doing this?
- Is this the correct way to achieve this?
- Is there a more idiomatic way of implementing this functionality?

The system contains several traits, so making a single trait using methods of all the other traits seems like a bad idea. Several traits have more than one method, so replacing them with closures is not possible.

**What I have tried**

As one object may produce one or more `Rc<Trait>`, we might envision implementing this with a `HashMap<ID, Vec<Rc<Any>>>` whereby we make each struct have a unique `ID`, which maps to a list of all `Rc` that have been made for it.

When we want to remove an object, we remove it from the corresponding list, and remove the entry in the hashmap, invalidating all `Weak` references.

However, implementing this fails, as to insert into the `HashMap`, one must upcast a `Rc<Trait>` -> `Rc<Any>`, only to downcast it later.

Comment: *Is there a way of doing this?* and *Is this the correct way to achieve this?* are somewhat at odds. Does the solution you have do what you want, or not? If not, what is wrong about it?

Comment: Sorry my wording was unclear. I don't have a compiling solution.

Comment: While you can cast a convert a `Rc<struct> -> Rc<Trait>` by cloning, and then convert a reference to that to `Weak<Trait>` using `Rc::downgrade`, I have not found a suitable way to first store the `Rc<Trait>` into a sequence of a supertype (for example `Vec<Rc<Any>>`, and then downcast the reference to the supertype back into a reference to the original type (`&Rc<Any> -> &Rc<Trait>`) .

Comment: I've answered at least [two](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27892375/can-i-do-type-introspection-with-trait-objects-and-then-downcast-it) [questions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40024093/downcast-traits-inside-rc-for-ast-manipulation?noredirect=1&lq=1) about downcasting in Rust. I'm thinking of another one (not written by me) but I can't find it right now. Does one of those answer your question?

Comment: The main gist of this question isn't about down-casting - rather obtaining Weak<Trait> references - this provides two important features - maintaining a single "owner" of data, while also allowing treating multiple references the same - i.e holding a sequence of `vec<Weak<Trait>>`, rather than several lists of each independent type. It just so happens that in my example I have an issue with downcasting (but only because I upcasted immediately prior).

Comment: The use of downcast ref doesn't help, as the implementation I have tried requires converting a `&Rc<Any> -> &Rc<Trait>`, (unlike `&Rc<Any> -> Option<&Trait>`, which `downcast_ref` provides). It seems the only way to do this is to use `std::mem::transmute()`, which doesn't seem very idiomatic.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure if this is the idiomatic way of doing this, but I've since developed a crate providing this functionality - [`dependent_view`](https://crates.io/crates/dependent_view).

Using the crate, the initial problem can be solved by using `DependentRc` instead of plain `Rc`'s:

```
struct ObjectManager {
    boxes: Vec<DependentRc<Box>>,
    panels: Vec<DependentRc<Panel>>,
    expressions: Vec<DependentRc<Expression>>
}

let object_manager : ObjectManager = ObjectManager::new();
```

Then using macros provided by the crate, we can obtain `Weak<>` references to these structs:

```
let box_view : Weak<Drawable> = to_view!(object_manager.boxes[0]);
let panel_view : Weak<Drawable> = to_view!(object_manager.panels[0]);
let expression_view : Weak<Drawable> = to_view!(object_manager.expressions[0]);
```

With this, dropping the corresponding `DependentRc<>` will invalidate all `Weak<>` references that have been made of it.