# Is it possible to implement a custom Iterator::sum in Rust?

Tags: iterator, rust

I am trying to learn about iterators with an iterator that produces triangle numbers. Triangle numbers are 1, 3, 6, 10, 15 where 1 = 1, 3 = 1 + 2, 6 = 1 + 2 + 3 etc. I have the basics of this created:

```
pub struct Triangle {
    cur: u32,
    n: u32,
    m: u32,
}

impl Iterator for Triangle {
    type Item = u32;

    fn next(&mut self) -> Option<u32> {
        if self.n == self.m {
            return None;
        }
        self.n = self.n + 1;
        self.cur = self.cur + self.n;

        Some(self.cur)
    }
}
```

A quick runnable example of this is

```
let t = Triangle { cur: 0, n: 0, m: 10 };
let s: u32 = t.sum();
println!("{}", s);  // prints 220
```

Is it possible to create a custom summation function for the iterator that returns type `u32`? I was hoping to be able to do this with the default iterator and sum functions, and not have to make my own specialized function.

What I was hoping to be able to do is:

```
use std::iter::Sum;

impl Sum<u32> for u32 {
    fn sum<I>(iter: I) -> Self
    where
        I: Triangle,
    {
        let nsum = (self.n * (self.n + 1) * (self.n + 2)) / 6;
        let msum = (self.m * (self.m + 1) * (self.m + 2)) / 6;
        msum - nsum
    }
}
```

but this does not work. The error that I get with this is

```
error[E0404]: expected trait, found struct `Triangle`
  --> src/main.rs:26:12
   |
26 |         I: Triangle,
   |            ^^^^^^^^ not a trait
```

I could change it from `Triangle` to `Iterator` like it wants, but that would prevent me from accessing the `m` and `n` values of the `Triangle` struct.

How do I do this? Is it impossible? I know that I could write my own function like `my_sum()`, but I was hoping to be able to do it in the context of an iterator.

Comment: Perhaps [How do I implement a trait I don't own for a type I don't own?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/25413201/155423) will explain everything you need to know?

Comment: @Shepmaster I think it's not really about that, but about providing an efficient O(1) implementation for the `Triangle` iterator. I sense that overriding `Iterator::sum()` is the solution... maybe.

Comment: I have removed the dependancy on `Num` and added an example of sum working initially.

Comment: In the `sum` function, `iter` is a trait. Downcasting is only defined for `'static` data. See [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/27892569/33499)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You cannot specialize the existing implementation of `Sum`, but you can specialize [`Iterator::sum`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/stable/std/iter/trait.Iterator.html#method.sum) in your iterator! It's a bit tricky, though, since its return type is generic.

```
use std::iter::{self, Sum};

impl Iterator for Triangle {
    // existing members are unchanged

    fn sum<S>(self) -> S
    where
        S: Sum<Self::Item>,
    {
        let nsum = (self.n * (self.n + 1) * (self.n + 2)) / 6;
        let msum = (self.m * (self.m + 1) * (self.m + 2)) / 6;
        S::sum(iter::once(msum - nsum))
    }
}
```

We cannot return a fixed type (such as `u32`), as that would not respect the contract defined by the `Iterator` trait. All we know about the return type `S` is that it implements `Sum<Self::Item>`. [`Sum`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/stable/std/iter/trait.Sum.html) has a single method, [`sum`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/stable/std/iter/trait.Sum.html#tymethod.sum), that returns `Self`, so we can use it to produce a value of type `S`. The method expects an iterator; we feed it a [`Once`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/stable/std/iter/struct.Once.html), "an iterator that yields an element exactly once". Since that iterator will iterate a fixed number of times, we can expect `sum` to perform a fixed number of operations.

When you compile the program in release mode and `S` is `u32`, the whole `sum` call is optimized away, and the function returns `msum - nsum` directly.